# Matrix Norm Inequality Implies Invertibility

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces

Could you prove me some hints to prove the following theorem?

If $A$ is a non-singular matrix, and $B$ is a matrix such that:
$$
\|B-A\|<\frac{1}{\|A^{-1}\|},
$$
then $B$ is non-singular and that:
$$
B^{-1}=A^{-1}\Sigma_{j=0}^{\infty}(I-BA^{-1})^{j}
$$
Here, $\|\cdot\|$ denotes the matrix norm:
$$
\|A\|=\sup\frac{\|Ax\|}{\|x\|}
$$
There are two parts in this theorem: the first is to prove that $B$ is non-singular, and the second is to prove the formula for the inverse of $B$. I am stuck at both.

Comment: See [Neumann series: The set of invertible operators is open](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neumann_series#The_set_of_invertible_operators_is_open).

Answer (score 0):

Note that from $\|B-A\|<\frac{1}{\|A^{-1}\|}$, we know

$$
\|I-BA^{-1}\|=\|(I-BA^{-1})AA^{-1}\|=\|(A-B)A^{-1}\|\leq\|(A-B)\|\|A^{-1}\| <1$$
So the geometric series of real numbers
$$\Sigma_{j=0}^{\infty}\|(I-BA^{-1})\|^{j}$$
is converging, hence the corresponding matrix series is converging as well:
$$M:=\Sigma_{j=0}^{\infty}(I-BA^{-1})^{j}$$

Furthermore let us do a direct computation showing $(I-BA^{-1})M = M-I$:
$$(I-BA^{-1})M = (I-BA^{-1})\Sigma_{j=0}^{\infty}(I-BA^{-1})^{j} \\=\Sigma_{j=1}^{\infty}(I-BA^{-1})^{j}=\\
(I-BA^{-1})+ (I-BA^{-1})^2 + (I-BA^{-1})^3 +... =\\
(I + (I-BA^{-1})+ (I-BA^{-1})^2 + (I-BA^{-1})^3 +... ) -I =\\
 \left(\Sigma_{j=0}^{\infty}(I-BA^{-1})^{j}\right)-I \\ =M-I$$

Thus $BA^{-1}M=I$, which shows that $A^{-1}M$ is the inverse of $B$.

Comment: How do you go from:
$$\Sigma_{j=1}^{\infty}(I-BA^{-1})^{j}$$
to
$$=\left(\Sigma_{j=0}^{\infty}(I-BA^{-1})^{j}\right)-I$$

Comment: @Slow Learner : I added 2 lines in the answer, to explain this in a bit more detail. Mainly it is about adding and subtracting $I$ at the same time.